# JSON Not Valid when URL Entered but Valid when copyed and pasted

Tags: php, javascript, json, windows-8

I am trying to validate the following URL of JSON for a Windows 8 app. The problem is that the following code is run it will not bind to the listbox provided. I know the code works and have singled it down to the JSON I have created.

```
 new WinJS.Binding.List(json.results);
```

The JSON seen on this website is showing up as valid on websites...

```
https://example.com/app/example.php
```

..if I copy and paste the URL into the JSON valadator such as jsonlint.com i get:

```
Parse error on line 1 <\!DOCTYPEhtmlPUBLIC" ^ Expecting '{', '['
```

..but when i copy and paste the code the URL is valid.

I know this is a simple solution to this but i cannot get it working for the life of me. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the URL doesn't return a proper JSON response. It returns an HTML response that contains JSON in a formatted code block. So while copying and pasting it will work, your code will see all the HTML that wraps it and break (because it's invalid).

If this is an API you control, you need to set the `Content-type` header in the PHP script (`header('Content-type: application/json')`), and return nothing but the JSON string, without any HTML code at all.

If it's not, your best bet is to fetch the URL and then strip all the HTML from the response so you can parse the remaining JSON. A DOM parsing library might help you do this.

Edit: it appears the response is now (or was already) correct, and it validates fine at http://jsonlint.com.

Comment: Thank you, had the application/json before while testing and has some reason commented it out without realizing. Validated fine after adding <?php
header("Content-type: application/json");